# RabbitMQ users are deleted after pod restart

Tags: linux, kubernetes, rabbitmq, rhel

I'm running RabbitMQ on a Kubernetes cluster. I have mounted only log location and config location of the RabbitMQ. When the pod restarts, all the users I have created are lost. Anyway way to mount user details?

Comment: just to clarify - is it only the users - or do u lose all the other structures as well - like queues and exchanges that u created?

Comment: @code_kbd Queue details are preserved under the 'Guest' user because its the default one. But queues under a different user are lost.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to mount the `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE` , this is the path under which RabbitMQ generally creates it's database with all the user and queue info.

You may refer to the RabbitMQ Documentation [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) for more details